# WatsonApiException: Error: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials , Code: 401

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, language-translation

I'm trying to connect to a Language Translator instance as per the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/language-translator/api/v2/python.html?python#introduction):

```py
!pip install --upgrade "watson-developer-cloud>=1.4.0"

import json
from watson_developer_cloud import LanguageTranslatorV2

translator = LanguageTranslatorV2(
    iam_api_key='***my_api_key***',
    url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api'
)

models = translator.list_models()
print(json.dumps(models, indent=2))
```

However, this results in:

```
WatsonApiException: Error: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials , Code: 401 , Information: {'description': 'No credentials supplied.'} , X-dp-watson-tran-id: xxxxxx , X-global-transaction-id: xxxxx
```

I found the API Key in the service credentials.  I tried both `apikey` and `iam_apikey_name` but both result in the same error:

```
{
 “apikey”: “***my_api_key***”,
 “iam_apikey_description”: “Auto generated apikey during resource-key operation for Instance - crn:v1:bluemix:public:language-translator:us-south:xxxxxx::“,
 “iam_apikey_name”: “auto-generated-apikey-xxxxxx",
 “iam_role_crn”: “crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam::::serviceRole:Manager”,
 “iam_serviceid_crn”: “crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam-identity::xxxxxx::serviceid:ServiceId-xxxxxx",
 “url”: “https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api”
}
```

I also tried creating a Platform API Key for IBM Cloud. Same error.

I also tried creating an access token:

```
%%bash
curl -k -X POST \
  --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --data-urlencode "grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey" \
  --data-urlencode "apikey=**myapikey**" \
  "https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token"
```

Then using the access token returned by curl:

```
translator = LanguageTranslatorV2(iam_access_token='**generated_access_token**')
```

Same error :(

I think this issue is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703766/ibm-watson-visual-recognition-access-is-denied-due-to-invalid-credentials) posted for VisualRecognition, but in this case for LanguageTranslator.

Comment: Which instance? The announcement says that not all have been migrated https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/language-translator/release-notes.html#release-notes

Comment: Just finding out.  I'm posting on behalf of another user who is hitting issues going through the tutorial https://www.ibm.com/cloud/garage/tutorials/ibm-watson-studio-machine-learning/ibm-watson-studio-ml-dl-made-easy

Comment: @data_henrik I just tried with a new service created in US South. I tried different ways to setup the library (question has been updated).  All produced the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language Translator now has a V3 version of the service.  Perhaps you created a V3 service instance?  If so, you need to use the `LanguageTranslatorV3` module in the Watson Python SDK.